# SeekBar Two Way Data Binding not updating TextView

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a data-bound layout with a SeekBar and a TextView that should show the selected value. At first, it works, but this layout is inside a RecyclerView with other data-bound layouts, after scrolling for a bit, it stops working (the TextView stops updating when changing the selected value). I imagine it can be a problem with the adapter and bind logic, but I need help to identify it.

This is the layout file (removed the other views, margins and constraints to make it more readable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type=".EffectUiModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="@={viewModel.seekSelection}"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSeekBarValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.seekSelection.toString()}"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

and this is the Data Model:

```
class EffectUiModel(effect: Effect) : DataBoundModel(R.layout.effect_list_item) {

    val name = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = effect.name }
    val description = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = effect.description }
    val type = MutableLiveData<EffectType>().apply { value = effect.type }
    val seekSelection = MutableLiveData<Int>()
}
```

This Data Model extends from DataBoundModel, as you can see, it simply holds the layout ID and use it for the recycling logic:

```
open class DataBoundModel(@LayoutRes val layout: Int)
```

The whole idea here is that I can have a Recycler View with different data-bound models inside, and recycling and binding should be working automatically (and it has been thus far, except for this case). Here is the adapter:

```
class DataBoundRecyclerAdapter(val items: List<DataBoundModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DataBoundViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return items[position].layout
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DataBoundViewHolder {
        val binding: ViewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), viewType, parent, false)
        return DataBoundViewHolder(binding).also { binding.lifecycleOwner = it }
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataBoundViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, items[position])
        holder.binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: DataBoundViewHolder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
        holder.markAttach()
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: DataBoundViewHolder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
        holder.markDetach()
    }

}
```

and here is the ViewHolder:

```
class DataBoundViewHolder(val binding: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), LifecycleOwner {

    private val lifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)

    fun markAttach() {
        lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
    }

    fun markDetach() {
        lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED
    }

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        return lifecycleRegistry
    }

}
```

I then simply create the data-bound models and add them to a list, then create the adapter and set it to the recycler view. What can possibly be wrong here?

EDIT:

Here is an image of the layout after it has bugged, original value was `null`, I selected 85, scrolled down on the recycler view, came back up, the seekbar was properly marking 85, but after changing it again the text no longer got updated:

[image: Image Showing the error]

Comment: Have you tryed to use Transformation to update the textview value ? i think this can resolve your problem.

Comment: @victorldavila that did not work. I even tried creating my own binding adapter and the same issue happens. I guess there might be something wrong with the adapter but I cannot possible find it.